# jQuery accordion - how to collapse other open accordion panes when another one is opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion that I want to have the following functionality: when the user clicks on a link to expand, the other expanded links (if any) will collapse. I know this functionality is built in the accordion plugin, but I'm trying to avoid adding another library (jQuery UI).

EDIT: Here is the code I have right now (here it is on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2Jfs/2/):

```
    $('.accordion-toggler').addClass('toggle-plus');

    $('.accordion-toggler').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('toggle-plus')) {
            $this.removeClass('toggle-plus').addClass('toggle-minus');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('toggle-minus').addClass('toggle-plus');
        }
        $this.next('.mod-content').slideToggle();
    });
```

The "mod-content" class is attached to the content that should be expanded/collapsed. Right now, if you expand one item, leave it open, then click another, you have more than one expanded areas. How can I collapse other links except for the active one?

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net or demo site?

Comment: Just a note, the `$` symbol is not required to prepend your Javascript variable `$this`. You can simply use `this` instead.

Comment: You can try to move this line to top and use siblings instead of next to target all others: `$this.siblings('.mod-content').slideToggle();`, Then show the current one. Can you post some HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this way more complicated than it has to be. If you're simply wanting one to slide down while the others slide back up, use the following code...

```
$('.accordion-toggler').click(function() {
    var targetElement = $(this).next('.mod-content');
    targetElement.slideToggle();
    targetElement.siblings('.mod-content').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works to do what I asked. However, I still want to have the option to collapse all if needed (there may be a long list).

Comment: I made some revisions which should do what you want.

Comment: I added your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/ellenchristine/s2Jfs/4/. However, now you can see that the default behavior is having none of the lists showing, so you can't really interact with the links.

Comment: Oops, sorry bout that. It helped to see the html from your jsfiddle. I removed the first `$('.mod-content').slideUp();` and it works fine now.